# Cache invalidation algorithm

Tags: caching, invalidation

I'm thinking about *caching dynamic content* in web server. My goal is to *bridge the whole processing* by returning a cached HTTP response without bothering the DB (or Hibernate). This question is not about choosing between existing caching solutions; my current concern is the invalidation.

I'm sure, a time-based invalidation makes no sense at all: Whenever a user changes anything, they expect to see to the effect immediately rather than in a few seconds or even minutes. And caching for a fraction of a second is useless as there are no repeated requests for the same data in such a short period (since most of the data is user-specific).

For every data change, I get an event and can use it to invalidate everything depending on the changed data. As request happen concurrently, there are two time-related problems:

- Invalidation may come too late and stale data may be served even to the client who changed them.
- After the invalidation has finished, a long running request may finish and its stale data may get put into the cache.

The two problems are sort of opposite to each other. I guess, the former is easily solved by partially serializing requests from the same client using a `ReadWriteLock` per client. So let's forget it.

The latter is more serious as it basically means a **lost invalidation** and serving the stale data forever (or too long).

I can imagine a solution like repeating the invalidation after every request having started before the change happened, but this sounds rather complicated and time-consuming. I wonder if any existing caches do support this, but I'm mainly interested in how this gets done in general.

#### Clarification

The problem is a simple race condition:

- Request A executes a query and fetches the result
- Request B does some changes
- The invalidation due to B happens
- Request A (which was delayed for whatever reason) finishes
- The *obsolete* response by request A gets written into the cache

Comment: Is the caching system going to be integrated with the application or separate?

Comment: @Rei It'll be integrated as tightly as needed.

Comment: I don't know how this is done in general but when I needed an integrated caching system, I looked around for existing solutions and found only time-based caching. I decided to write my own and it turned out to be simpler than I expected and definitely more effective because it has none of the problems of time-based that you already figured out. That *data change event* is the key.

Comment: @Rei That's what I'm trying. My current problem is a race condition between the data change event and a late response; I've just added a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the race condition, add a timestamp (or a counter) and check this timestamp when setting a new cache entry.
This ensures that obsolete response will not be cached.

Here's a pseudocode:

```js
//set new cache entry if resourceId is not cached
//or if existing entry is stale
function setCache(resourceId, requestTimestamp, responseData) {
    if (cache[resourceId]) {
        if (cache[resourceId].timestamp > requestTimestamp) {
            //existing entry is newer
            return;
        } else
        if (cache[resourceId].timestamp = requestTimestamp) {
            //ensure invalidation
            responseData = null;
        }
    }

    cache[resourceId] = {
        timestamp: requestTimestamp,
        response: responseData
    };
}
```

Let's say we got 2 requests for the same resource "foo":

- Request A (received at 00:00:00.000) executes a query and fetches the result
- Request B (received at 00:00:00.001) does some changes
- The invalidation due to B happens by calling `setCache("foo", "00:00:00.001", null)`
- Request A finishes
- Request A calls `setCache("foo", "00:00:00.000", ...)` to write the obsolete response to cache but fails because the existing entry is newer

This is just the basic mechanism, so there is room for improvements.

Comment: This sounds very simple and fool-proof and I'm sure, I've tried it.... but I can't recall what made me to refuse it (one week may be too much for my poor memory). Now, I believe, it should work.

Comment: That happens to me too, which is why I have to force myself to comment my codes. I don't always succeed, because writing code is so much more fun than writing comments. :-)

Comment: I've fixed it in the meantime... using the starting date for the invalidation and keeping the invalid entry is both necessary. There was a different bug there and somehow I managed to convince me that the invalidation is the culprit. `+++` Now, there's the problem with forcing the cache to keep the invalid entry as long as necessary (i.e., until all overlapping requests finish), but that's a different question. `+++` The bounty is definitely yours, but I'm keeping it a while more, maybe someone adds some useful idea.

Comment: @maaartinus Sure thing. I would love to get new ideas on this and improve my own code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't realize (or don't want to explicitly call out) that you are asking about a choice between cache synchronization strategies. There are several well known strategies: "cache aside", "read through", "write through", and "write behind". e.g. read here: [A beginner’s guide to Cache synchronization strategies](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cache-synchronization-strategies/). They offer various levels of cache consistency (invalidation as you call it).

*Your choice should depend on your needs and requirements.*

It sounds like so far you've chosen "write behind" strategy (queue or defer cache invalidation). But from your concerns it sounds like you've chosen it incorrectly, because you are worried about inconsistent cache reads.

So, you should consider using "cache aside" or "read/write through" strategies, because those offer better cache consistency. They all are different flavors of the same thing - *always keep cache consistent*. If you don't care about cache consistency, then ok, stay with "write behind", but then this question becomes irrelevant.

Architecture wide, I would never go with raising events to invalidate the cache, because it seems like you've made it part of your business logic, while it's just an infrastructure concern. Invalidate (or queue invalidation of) cache as part of read/write operations, and not somewhere else. That allows cache to become just one aspect of your infrastructure, and not part of everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article but unfortunately it doesn't apply here. The article is about data caching where data duplication occurs (you have data in your database and identical data in cache). The question is about HTTP response caching where no duplication occurs. The purpose is to avoid redoing lengthy processing if the HTTP response is going to be identical anyway. A separate caching system for this purpose is called web accelerator, but it is intended for static content or dynamic content with acceptable staleness. Stale response of any degree is unacceptable in OP's case.

Comment: Borrowing a data caching term, **strong consistency** is required here, so a comparable strategy is definitely not "write behind". Of course, they are not actually comparable because data caching and HTTP response caching are two different things. Let me know if I should explain further.

Comment: Rei is right, but I appreciate your answer as it makes me re-evaluate my decisions. The events are raised rather automatically by just listening to Hibernate committing and they're processed immediately. There's some business logic there, but it's simple: 1. Event coarsening as there's no need to watch each single item separately when there are only requests returning collections of them. 2. Some things aren't worth caching and therefore changes of some entities can be simply ignored. These two points are possibly premature optimizations.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you both are speaking about concurrency problem that question has. You need to give up that problem, since consistency will kill availability, specifically you would have to do either locking or redo the delayed request again. If you don't want to bother with that, just live with eventual consistency (yes these terms come from distributed apps, but apply here too). If request A delayed, yes, it will have a stale data for that 1 time, but you should live with it. Eventually, when the cache is invalidated, request A next time will have the right data. SO does that for feed IMO.